# Increase number in text file by random amount

Tags: php

I have this php code:

```
$counter = file_get_contents($_GET["username"].".txt") + 1;
```

So if someone opens the page with "?username=abc", the number in abc.txt will increase by 1.

How can I change this to increase by a random amount between 0.00001-0.00000001?

I also need weighted chance. I need it to have a higher chance to increase by a lower number than a higher number.

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability#PHP. ASAP!

Comment: How can I fix this?